# How to generate SSHFP records with OpenWrt/Dropbear?

Tags: openwrt, ssh-keygen, dropbear

How to generate SSHFP records for a Dropbear instance at OpenWrt? I have **dropbearconvert** and **openssh-keygen** installed, but nothing works. Always `invalid format` or similar errors. There are two host key files available:

```
/etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key
/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
```

Any ideas how to get a SSHFP record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbear uses its own format for key storage and public keys are not on file.

The **dropbearkey** binary can be used to generate keys and convert between formats.

```
dropbearkey -y -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key > /tmp/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh-keygen -r host.example.net -f /tmp/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

See https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/master/README for the full story ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for the moment:

```
sshfp -a -s <IP>
```

This works on an Ubuntu client, but I would prefer an OpenWrt-only way.